# SQL - values from two rows into new two rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that gives a sum of quantity of items on working days. on weekend and holidays that quantity value and item value is empty.
I would like that on empty days is last known quantity and item.
My query is like this:

```
`select a.dt,b.zaliha as quantity,b.artikal as item
from
(select to_date('01-01-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY') + rownum -1 dt 
from dual 
connect by level <= to_date(sysdate) - to_date('01-01-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY') + 1
order by 1)a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(select kolicina,sum(kolicina)over(partition by artikal order by datum_do) as zaliha,datum_do,artikal
from
(select sum(vv.kolicinaulaz-vv.kolicinaizlaz)kolicina,vz.datum as   datum_do,vv.artikal
from vlpzaglavlja vz, vlpvarijante vv
where vz.id=vv.vlpzaglavlje
and vz.orgjed='01006'
and vv.skladiste='01006'
and vv.artikal in (3069,6402)
group by vz.datum,vv.artikal
order by vv.artikal,vz.datum asc)
order by artikal,datum_do asc)b
on a.dt=b.datum_do
where a.dt between to_date('12102017','ddmmyyyy') and     to_date('16102017','ddmmyyyy')
order by a.dt`
```

and my output is like this:

[image: Current Output]

and I want this:

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: Why don't you just add the lines to the question instead of going through the hassle to create and upload images of text snippets?

Comment: sorry, didnt know how to...

Comment: I think this requires a stored procedure and some cursor. If you can simplify and format your code you'd increase the chance to get an answer.

Comment: Showing us your query is helpful. What would also be helpful is to post CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements to recreate small samples of the base tables.

Comment: What kind of simplification I should apply?

Comment: After lots of thinking...It would be helpful to add another column in query: DT_NEW and in that column would be the date only where filed quatity is null and that would be the last date where quantity is not null.same date on both positions...where dt=14/10/2017 and 15/10/2017 on that position DATE_NEW should be 13/10/2017. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

In short, if quantity is null use `lag(... ignore nulls)` and `coalesce` or `nvl`:

```
select dt, item, 
       nvl(quantity, lag(quantity ignore nulls) over (partition by item order by dt))
  from t
  order by dt, item
```

Here is the full query, I cannot test it, but it is something like:

```
with t as (
  select a.dt, b.zaliha as quantity, b.artikal as item
    from ( 
      select date '2017-10-10' + rownum - 1 dt 
        from dual 
        connect by date '2017-10-10' + rownum - 1 <= date '2017-10-16' ) a
      left join (
        select kolicina, datum_do, artikal,
               sum(kolicina) over(partition by artikal order by datum_do) as zaliha
          from (
            select sum(vv.kolicinaulaz-vv.kolicinaizlaz) kolicina, 
                   vz.datum as datum_do, vv.artikal
              from vlpzaglavlja vz 
              join vlpvarijante vv on vz.id = vv.vlpzaglavlje
              where vz.orgjed = '01006' and vv.skladiste='01006' 
                and vv.artikal in (3069,6402)
              group by vz.datum, vv.artikal)) b
        on a.dt = b.datum_do)
select * 
  from (
    select dt, item, 
           nvl(quantity, lag(quantity ignore nulls) 
                         over (partition by item order by dt)) qty
      from t)
  where dt >= date '2017-10-12'
  order by dt, item
```

There are several issues in your query, major and minor:

- in date generator (subquery `a`) you are selecting dates from long period, january to september, then joining with main tables and summing data and then selecting only small part. Why not filter dates at first?,
- `to_date(sysdate)`. `sysdate` is already date,
- use ansi joins,
- do not use `order by` in subqueries, it has no impact, only last ordering is important,
- use date literals when defining dates, it is more readable.

Comment: No, with this query my result set look like this: `1 12/10/2017 3069 11037
2 12/10/2017 6402 25000
3 13/10/2017 3069 14175
4 13/10/2017 6402 20322
5 14/10/2017  
6 15/10/2017  
7 16/10/2017 3069 15035
8 16/10/2017 6402 13092`
'